# how to remove the \ character from a string in haskell

Tags: haskell

Hi guys i am trying to write a function that removes just the '' character from strings in haskell

I have created a list comprehension to remove `\"` but i actaully want to keep that " within my string.

Here's an example of what i am looking for:

given `"today \"tomorrow\"." becomes "today ""tomorrow""."`

this is what i have so far is there a way for me to just remove the `\`

```
removeVal xs = [ x | x <- xs, not (x `elem` "\"") ]
```

this function returns output `"today tomorrow."`
instead of what i want stated above

Comment: The `\\` is *not* part of the *content* of the string, these appear in the *representation* of the string.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry i copied the list comp over wrong this is what i have is there a way just to remove \

Comment: search for "escape character".

Answer (score 2):

There **is no** `\` character in the string `"today \"tomorrow\"."`.

```
Prelude> putStrLn "today \"tomorrow\"."
today "tomorrow".
```

The reason such a string is normally displayed with the `"` characters escaped is that they would obviously terminate the string literal, which would lead to funny parsing / type errors.

```
Prelude> "today "tomorrow"."

<interactive>:2:1: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘t0 -> [Char] -> t’
                  with actual type ‘[Char]’
    • The function ‘"today "’ is applied to two arguments,
      ...
```

One way to avoid the problem is to avoid using ASCII double-quote characters. The preferred symbols for quotation marks are U+201c LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK and U+201d RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK.

```
Prelude> putStrLn "today “tomorrow”."
today “tomorrow”.
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer so by their being no \ within the string is there away to get it not to display within the string so that it would be "today "tomorrow"." that is returned or is that viable like you said above and would lead to some weird parsing?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. It _is_ returned with no `\ `, there never _was_ any backslash there. — Of course, if you ask GHCi to present such a string as a Haskell literal by calling `show` or `print`, it has to escape the double-quote characters, because that's the only way you can have double quotes in a Haskell string literal. Don't use `show` if that's not the behaviour you want.